# Regular expression with RedirectMatch does anything

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, redirect, httpd.conf

I use .htaccess to perform redirection. 
Here the line

```
RedirectMatch permanent .*\?langue=([\w]{2}).*id_([\w]+)=([1-9]+) ***[protocol]***://myserver/rootContext/action?pagename=dir1/dir2/dir3/Redirect&type=$2&id=$3&lang=$1
```

Here my inital url:

```
***[protocol]***://localhost/adir/anotherDir/anotherDirAgian/oneMore/apage.php?langue=fr&id_dossier=261
```

This regular expression is correct, but at least, no redirection is done.
With silmple regular expression and simple url it works correctly.

Does somebody can help?
Thanks
David Hoareau

Answer (score 1):

[RedirectMatch](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html#redirectmatch) operates against the ‘URL-path’, which does not include any query parameters.

You can match against a query string by using a [RewriteCond](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond) in mod_rewrite. Although IMO it's a dodgy proposition trying to parse query strings with regex. Any unexpected parameters or ordering could break your regex. Since you aren't matching a particular path, it could also go wrong if any URL in the new system contained `?langue=...` in the query.

Answer (score 0):

Beside that what bobince already said, try this mod_rewrite rule:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(([^&]*&)*)langue=(\w{2}.*)
RewriteCond %1lang=%3 ^(([^&]*&)*)id_([\w]+)=([1-9]+.*)
RewriteRule .* $0?%1type=%3&id=%4
```

The substitution URL must be adjusted to your needs but the query substitution should be correct.